# MySQL Return id where occurance count > attribute value

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have two table:

```
Bike__________________________       Kiosk
```

With columns:

```
BikeID, Location_________________    KioskID, Capacity
```

and data such as:

```
1, 1 ___________________________     1, 10  
2, 1 ___________________________     2, 5  
3, 1 ___________________________     3, 15 
4, 2  
5, 1
```

etc...  Location is a foreign key that points to kioskid. I am trying to write a query that returns only the KioskIDs of kiosks that have capacity. In other words, if 7 bikes are parked at kiosk 1, kiosk 1 is returned. If 5 bikes are parked at kiosk 2 it is not returned. I was able to write code that returns the count of bikes at each kiosk, but am confused as to how to use this (nested query?) to return only the kiosks whose capacity>count(*).

```
SELECT k.kioskid, COUNT(*)  
FROM kiosk AS k  
JOIN bike AS b ON b.location = k.kioskid  
GROUP BY k.kioskid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
SELECT kioskid, COUNT(location), capacity
FROM kiosk AS k  
JOIN bike  ON location = kioskid  
GROUP BY kioskid 
HAVING COUNT(location)  < capacity;
```

Two issues I found with this error after delving into the issue further. 1. since MySQL works inside out, so any alias established by the AS clause must exist in the inner most code -- inn this case the HAVING clause. 2. The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well. So by removing all aliases and including capacity in the SELECT clause, I got the code to work finally. Thanks @Lieven Keersmaekers and @Jim Dennis for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. All that's needed is a `HAVING` clause to compare the amount of bikes per kiosk to the capacity.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f258b/2)

```
SELECT k.kioskid
FROM   kiosk k
       left outer join bike b on b.location = k.kioskid
GROUP BY
       k.kioskid
HAVING 
       COUNT(*) < MAX(k.Capacity)
```

As a sidenote, I strongly recommend to rename the `location` column to `kioskid` as to implicitly make it clear what the foreign key relation is.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I should follow better naming conventions, you are correct there. However, I had tried this before and am now coming up with the same error. Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Capacity' in 'having clause'
I thought perhaps it should be k.Capacity, but I get the same error. MySQL is giving me issues. Other ideas?

Comment: @BigData - I don't have a mysql to try and my sql is a bit rusty but can you try the new version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) as in:

```
SELECT k.kioskid, COUNT(kiosk.location) AS cap
FROM kiosk AS k  
JOIN bike AS b ON b.location = k.kioskid  
GROUP BY k.kioskid HAVING cap > k.capacity
```

Comment: Thank  you for the response. I got another error, Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'kiosk.location' in 'field list'
I tried changing kiosk.location to bike.location as well as b.location, the error then changes to Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'k.capacity' in 'having clause'

Comment: The concept is right but I don't know your actual schema.